# Subgroup of GL(2,Z) generated by two matrices.

Tags: group-theory

What is the subgroup of $GL_2(Z)$ generated by the matrices:

$\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
$
and 
$\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)?
$

I would like to know the name(s) of this group, references to it, as well as its well-known actions. I have found it to be difficult to look up online, and not discussed in texts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the group is $\text{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$.

Indeed, note that
$$
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0\\
1&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{smallmatrix}
\right),$$
and thus your group contains $\text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ (see, e.g., Corollary 2.6 in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL%282,Z%29.pdf). On the other hand, your group is not contained in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, and since $[\text{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}):\text{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})]=2$ your group must be $\text{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was simple!

Comment: OMG! No, that matrix is not the product, in either order! Try again!

Comment: It is: compute $ATA$.

Comment: Will do. Thanks. :)

Comment: I still don't see it. You didn't specify which matrix was $A$, and which was $T$. But under both interpretations, I don't get the generator you specified. :/ Maybe I make an arithemtik error. Can we both check again?

Comment: @user96537 I was unclear before. See the edit.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks! I feel toopid now. ;)

Comment: Sorry, for the notations of $A$ and $T$ see my answer (and Eberhard's edited answer for $ATA$ ).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sean Eberhard's answer. The group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $U=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now $\langle A,T\rangle\simeq GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ for
$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and
$\langle B,T\rangle\simeq SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$
for $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. This was discussed in an earlier answer (with reference to 
www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf ).

Comment: I don't understand your answer, what do the angle brackets mean?

Comment: $\langle g_1,\ldots ,g_n\rangle$ means the subgroup of a group $G$ generated by the elements $g_1,\ldots ,g_n$.

Comment: Hmmn. That link doesn't seem to work for me when I copy and paste it into a new tab in Chrome. (I mean the link in your answer; I get  error.html.)  :/

Comment: But thank you both!

Comment: @user96537: I have corrected the link. Under http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ there is the paper called $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thanks, it works. :) Wish I could upvote you for your help.